# no bugs being reported from sonar c#

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

SonarC# 6.7.1 (build 4347)
SonarQube Version 6.7.1 (build 35068)

Quality Profile: Sonar way (outdated copy) because the current Sonar Way quality profile returns nothing at all.

Running the current MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner (SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.2.892) only reports Code Smells. No vulnerabilities or bugs are being reported.

Using https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples - CSharpProject to test. I've added bugs from the quality profile above into the code but they never get reported. I've tried this with other CS projects with the same results.

**Are there any known issues reporting vulnerabilities/bugs for C#? Is any additional configuration required to get this information reported back to SonarQube?**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a known issue, and I couldn't reproduce it using the same versions of the scanner, the C# plugin and a clean install of SonarQube 6.7.1.
Analysing the sample project reported one bug (csharpsquid:S2583, Program.cs line 9), and one code smell (csharpsquid:S1118, Program.cs line 4).

Code Smells, Bugs and Vulnerabilities are all handled the same way by the Scanner for MSBuild - they are all just Roslyn issues with different categories applied. No additional configuration is required.

I'm guessing you've migrated from an older version of SonarQube since you have an outdated SonarWay. However, that shouldn't make any difference to how issues are reported. The rules included in the default SonarWay might change between versions, but you've checked for rules you know are in the active QP.

If you haven't already, you could try installing [SonarLint for VS](https://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/) and checking it correctly detects the bugs you've injected into the code.

Other options:

- the .sonarqube\conf file will contain a ruleset file showing which rules are being executed by the scanner. Check that contains the expected rules.
- the bin directory of each project will contain a XXX.RoslynCA.json file containing all of the issues that were detected during the build. Check they contains the expected issues.
- check the console logs for errors or warnings. You could also increase the verbosity of the logged output by passing */d:sonar.verbose=true* on the command line in the *Begin* step.